# ImportError: No module named twisted.websocket

Tags: python, python-2.7, twisted, autobahn

I have tried one of [example](https://github.com/tavendo/AutobahnPython/blob/master/examples/twisted/websocket/slowsquare/client.py) web-socket client codes in autobahn web site. But it gives me the error

```
ImportError: No module named twisted.websocket
```

even though I have already installed autobahn. When I try to install "twisted" explicitly it tells me that "twisted" is already installed. I'm working on a Ubuntu machine.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to import a module `twisted.websocket` which doesn't exist (and never has).  The example has the module `autobahn.twisted.websocket`, which is part of autobahn, not twisted.

Comment: In my code I have "autobahn.twisted.websocket". This is just the error I get.

Answer (score 0):

The docs seem to be outdated/inaccurate. Try:

```
from autobahn.websocket import WebSocketServerProtocol
```